# WebView with Xampp

Tags: android, webview, xampp

I run a Xampp server and it seems to be well configured on my wireless network because I can access my apps using my local router IP 195.168.x.x from any computer's web browser and mobile browsers.

I am currently trying to make a Web app but when I try to load it into a WebView on my Android device I get a "CONNECTION REFUSED" error as if Xampp is blocking it (BUT: It does work if I type the same 195.168.x.x in my browser).

I tried several different things e.g. using the port, /index.php, etc. in my app build but none work. Sometimes I get the "Address is unreachable" error and sometimes when it seems to be loading after 5 seconds I get the "Connection Refused" one.

Also to clarify, I did use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in my app and everything works fine if I type an actual URL e.g. google.com.

[Connection Refused Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqtrk.png)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `Keep in mind it does work if I type the same 195.168.x.x in my browser). ` Try a browser on your Android device. Its yours too ;-).

Comment: It does work in any browser on any devices, sorry I should have said it above

Comment: So that url works in a browser on your device. And not in a webview on that device. Is that all?

Comment: `BUT: It does work if I type the same 195.168.x.x in my browser)` But in your webview you should type the protocol too `http://195.168.x.x`.

Comment: `I type an actual URL e.g. google.com.`. That is no url. That is a host name.

Comment: In my webview code if I type www.google.com, build the app, install it on my android it is a fullscreen web app that connects to google.com.

If I go to 195.168.1.5 on chrome on my mobile device it connects to my app like a website. 

If I type 195.168.1.5 or any other variants in my webview, build the app, install it, I get a Connection Refused. So I think there is something specificly blocking the app. trying to figure out what it is

Comment: `In my webview code if I type www.google.com ...` then it will not show a page as you have to tell the protocol too. You should type `http://www.google.com`. Ditto if you use an ip address.

Comment: I am typing "http://". Sorry I am not beeing as specific as I should in my comments. My problem is that if I type any online websites it will wrap and display in my android app, but if I type my local server router address it give me a connection refused error even if I can my app using my chrome browser on my android device. I am trying to figure out why it is only blocking the connection on the actual app